# I want split element of array make two value and pair with repeat value

Tags: php

i have array in php like this : `[1,2,3,4]`

i want split array then make two value pair like this :

`a` `[1,2]`

`b` `[2,3]`

`c` `[3,4]`

anyone can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far / what does your code look like? Where *specifically* in that attempt are you getting stuck? Show us a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would go `for` + `array_slice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$new_array = [];

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr) - 1; $i++){
  $new_array[] = [ $arr[$i], $arr[$i + 1] ];
}

The value of new_array is
[
   [1,2],
   [2,3],
   [3,4]
]
```